# How do I specify my resourcesXml for Glassfish as a resource itself, and not a local file?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I want to put all my configuration files (arquillian.xml, glassfish-resources.xml,test-persistence.xml) in a library and just reference that when i want to run a test in a project. But it seems the resourceXml only allows for a file-path and not a classpath: variable.

Is there a way to do that?

My configuration is currently based upon the arquillian-persistence-tutorial example project. I actually have no special configuration which is need. Just a in-memory db etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by extending the Arquillian class, and writing the resource to a local file (in the target folder) before any test.

Now in a domain project i only need to do this in a unit test:

```
public class MyEntityRepositoryImplTest extends BaseArquillianTest {

  @Deployment
  public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return create().//
        addClass(MyEntityRepositoryImpl.class).//
        addClass(MyEntityDaoImpl.class).//
        addClass(MockSomeRepositoryImpl.class).//
        addClass(MyEntityJpa.class);
  }

  @EJB
  private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

  @Test 
  public void mMytest () {
  }
```